# Fetching Sheet names from a excel sheet using file dialog picker

Tags: vba, excel

I have requirement, where I need to fetch worksheet names from a closed excel file and paste it on the column "A" of the "Sheet1" of active workbook.

Currently I am using this code, But it seems to fail when I am trying to run via Addin, This code is working fine if I paste this code in current workbook module.

Please Advise.

```
Sub GetTables()
Dim directory As String, file As String, sheet As Worksheet, fd As Office.FileDialog, wb As Workbook
Dim lastrow As Long

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)


With fd
.InitialFileName = "C:\data\Table Updates"
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Title = "Please select the file to get the records..."
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls?"


If .Show = True Then
file = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
End If
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


GetSheetsNames (file)
'Workbooks.Open (fileName)


End Sub


Function GetSheetsNames(file)
Dim lastrow As Long, c As Variant
lastrow = 1
Set sh = GetObject(file).Worksheets

For Each c In sh

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 1) = c.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 1) = Trim(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 1))
    lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
    MsgBox (c.Name)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next
End Function
```

Comment: When you run this as an **add-in**, make sure the active workbook has a `Sheet1 and that `Book1` exists.

Comment: I am sorry, Book1 clause was just for testing.I have edited it now.